# SQLite indexed value

Tags: android, duplicates, android-sqlite

How do I get single value from database in SQLite?
Here is my code:

```
public boolean checkResourceDuplcates(String insert) {
    Cursor result = databaseHelper.getResourceDuplicates();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (result.moveToNext()) {
        buffer.append(result.getString(0));
        String resultString = buffer.toString();
        if(insert == resultString){
            return true;
        }
    }return false;
}
```

I need to check for duplicates. As an argument, I place value from editText field.

Comment: try `if(insert.equals(resultString) { return true; }`. Saying that you could probably pass the string to check into `getResourceDuplicates` whose `WHERE` clause would check for the existence of the string and thus the cursor would contain any duplicates (using the count() e.g. `if(result.count() > 0) { return true; }`

Comment: I don't think that's it. I suppose that after while loop i get whole 'array' of Strings from database and I can't compare it to a single value.

Comment: `if(insert.equals(result.getString(0)) { return true }`

Comment: I used: 
if(resultString.contains(insert)){
            return true;
        }
But i appreciate your attention. Thanks :)

Comment: yes that would work, although less efficient as you are checking a potentially longer string. The main issue you had was that you were checking the objects as opposed to the properties (values) of the objects. i.e. `insert == resultString` would always be false as they are different objects.